# Как правильно поставить превдокласс

Tags: css

Селектор должен работать по логики вещей, этот селектор гласит: применять li относящегося ко всем UL кроме того что с классом .q77. Но почему то проблема осталась(саму проблему я решил просто интересно почему этот селектор не работает). Селектор на  строке 94 https://jsfiddle.net/cz8pz484/1/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}
.q1{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 top:0;left:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding-left:15%;
}
.q1>li{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 vertical-align:top;
 z-index:1000;
 height:42px;
 transition:all 1s;
 width:17%;
}
.q1>li img{
 position:absolute;
 top:5px;
 left:5px;
 transition:all .3s;
}
.q1>li>a{
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:12px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:#FF6633;
}
.q2{
 position:absolute;
 top:-90px;
 left:0; 
 width:100%;
 transition:all 1s;
 z-index:-1;
}
.q2>li{
 display:block; 
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 z-index:1000;
 margin-bottom:3px;
 transition:all .1s;
 float:left;
}
.q2>li> a{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:12px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:#336699;
}
.q1>li:hover .q2{
 top:45px;
}
.q1>li:hover img{
 transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.q1>li:hover{
 height:360px;
}
nav{
 position:relative;
 height:48px;
 margin:50px 0 0 0px;
}
.q2>li>a.q4{
 position:absolute;
 top:0; left:0;
 background:blue;
 transition:all 1s;
 z-index:-1;
}
.q2>li:hover{
  margin-left:5px;
}
.q2>li:hover a.q4{
  left:101.5%;
}
.q1 li:first-child .q2 .q4{
 right:0;
 left:auto;
}
.q1 li:first-child .q2 li:hover .q4{
  right:101.5%;
}
.q1 li:first-child ul:not(.q77) li:hover{
 float:right;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:3px;
}
.q2>li>.vid{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;top:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 transition:all 1s;
 z-index:-1;
}
.q2>li .vid .q44{
 display:inline-block;
 right:0;top:0;
 width:100%;
 padding:12px 0;
 background:green;
 transition:all 1s;
}
.q2>li .vid .q33{
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:black;
 transition:all 1s;
 z-index:-1;
}
.q2>li:hover .vid{
 right:101.5%;
}
.q2>li .vid:hover .q33{
 top:108%;
}
.q2>li>.vid .yu{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;top:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 transition:all 1s;
 z-index:-1;
 overflow:hidden;
 transition:all 1s;
}
.q2>li>.vid .yu:hover{
 height:180px;
}
.q2>li>.vid .yu .q55{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:12px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:black;
 z-index:-2;
}
.q2>li .vid:hover .yu{
 top:108%;
}
.q77{
 position:absolute;
 top:-90px;
 left:0; 
 width:100%;
 z-index:-3;
 transition:all 1s;
}
.q77 li{
 display:block;
 width:50%;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:3px;
}
.q77 li a{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:12px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:#336699;
}
.yu:hover .q77{
 top:45px;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
 <ul class="q1">
 <li>
 <a href="#">123<img src="line.png" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  <ul class="q2">
  <li><a href="#">333</a><div class="vid"><a href="#" class="q44">124</a><a href="#" class="q33">OoO</a></div></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a><a href="#" class="q4">123</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a><div class="vid"><a href="#" class="q44">124</a><div class="yu"><a href="#" class="q55">OoO</a><ul class="q77">
    <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
    </ul></div></div></li>
  </ul>
</li>
 <li>
 <a href="#">123</a>
  <ul class="q2">
  <li><a href="#">333</a><a href="#" class="q4">123</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a><a href="#" class="q4">123</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a><a href="#" class="q4">xaxaxa</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: советую вам сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример, то есть хотя бы поприбивать лишние селекторы пока проблема воспроизводится.

Comment: @Утка В этом и проблема поэтому я указал на 94 строку

Comment: Странноватая у вас реализация. Я бы посоветовал разворачивание перекинуть на JS, а там уже исключать будет легко. Не знаю, как на CSS такое сотворить

Comment: Вот селектор который гласит .q1 ul:not(.q77) li:hover: LI находящийся во всех UL кроме того что с классом .q77. Соответственно почему к LI который находится в .q77 всё ровно применяется правое выравнивание? https://jsfiddle.net/cz8pz484/3/ строка 94.